# How to determine the path to the file that starts the application in java

Tags: java, filepath

i want to ask you regardless finding the file path...

I have, or i would have files that will be associated with my app, but i dont know how to find out the file path that initializes opening my app.

For example:
If i click in windows enviroment on excel file "file.xlx", windows will open excel application with this file "file.xls" and i want exactly the same. After my app will be open, i want to know file path that inicializes my app to start...

I hope that my question is understandable and i apologize for my bad english.. :)

Edit:

I try add some another example...

I try describe some logic operations...

1 - nothing is running, only windows - i hope :)

2 - user click on some file that is somewhere in the HDD ( this file can have different name and different location )

3 - this file with some extension has associated start with my app

4 - app automatically find out on whitch file user clicked ( who invoke the launch of my application ) and use this file path on other work...

I think that should be something like when i start console app. with some argument....but this argument i must get from some windows location.
Just like when i click on file.txt and windows will open notepad and notepad will have automatically open this file.txt, or i click on file.dbf and windows will open the foxpro with this file

I want click on file.xxx and my app will open and work with this file automatically, so there i think must be some way how to get this file location on which i clicked...

I hope this help...

Comment: If it's a java app, your file will be `java` or `javaw` in your JRE dir. Do you need its location or something else?

Comment: What a file do you want to get path for?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the java system properties http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html, you probably want user.dir

Comment: my app will have still the same path (c:/programs/app.jar)
but the files will be everywhere...
if i click on file d:/somedirectory/file.xxx, my app will be opened and the app will autotically know the file path (d:/somedirectory/file.xxx) and will start working with this file...
Hope this hepl...

Answer (score 0):

i think what you need is a program like this , this will calculate the existance of your file in side the given directory

```
package fileSearch;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
public class fileSearch {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        fileSearch obj = new fileSearch();
        obj.finder("program.txt");
        for(int i=0;i<obj.finder("C:/Users/hussain.a/Desktop").length;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(obj.finder("C:/Users/hussain.a/Desktop")[i].getName());
        }
    }
    public File[] finder( String dirName){
        File dir = new File(dirName);

        return dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() { 
                 public boolean accept(File dir, String filename)
                      { return filename.endsWith(".txt"); }
        } );

    }

}
```

now its up to you to apply to your desired directory , if you want it to exactly like the windows program , then you will have to use root directory every time and pass the file name as a parameter replacing ".txt" in this program

hope it serves , rest is up to you to implement it

Comment: Thank you for your time and kind, but I think it is not what i am looking for because in your kode if i understand him, i know where i will looking for, but i'll have a file on any place a file can have a different name.
See my edited post with some another example, hope this will help...

Comment: dude i have mentioned that you have to use the root directory , as the given directory then it will search every where

Comment: yeah dude, but I do not need a list of files, then it would be for me better to use file chooser to find the file that I need ... see my modified question..

Answer (score 0):

I think you can set the os,like the registry,when you installing the app.

```
String osName = System.getProperty("os.name") ;
```